# How to print debug output in Rails 5 tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I would like to debug a test using `puts` or the logger. Neither is working for me. I am using Rails 5 and the standard testing setup included.

In a model test, an `ActiveSupport::TestCase`, attempts to print output disappear.

`puts` shows nothing, nor `STDOUT.puts`, `$stdout.puts`.

logger is undefined, `Rails.logger` produces no output to the terminal or the log/test.log file.

Comment: What is the log level in you test-environment? Which level are you using in your specs (`Rails.logger.debug` vs `Rails.logger.error` for ex). Is it possible you are using some custom logger? Check your test.rb under config/environments/ for those questions. Btw have you considered using `binding.pry`? It will stop the code and allow you to debug directly on console.

Comment: Rails.logger.error gives no output. All logging configuration was default, untouched.  Adding   config.log_level = :debug to config/environments/test.rb made no difference.

Comment: `puts` should not be affected by any logger setting. Make sure you reach the line that `puts` (or, better, put `puts` into the first line of the test.)

Comment: Tried that already. Does not work.

Comment: did you try puts variable_name.inspect?

Comment: I've tried just with strings.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the program even reaches to the point where you have the `puts` or logger line?

Comment: Is debugger suitable for you? I guess [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) would be a OK solution.

Answer (score 0):

To use logger you must add

```
require 'logger'
```

in your test file, then create a logger object and log something

```
logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.to_s + '/log/my_test.log' )
logger.info "---     Testing      ---"
```

Comment: I used Rails.logger = ... to capture the Rails.logger messages I use.